# How to install the game DCS?

Tags: wine, steam, winetricks, lutris

I m not able to run the **game DCS** (Digital Combat Simulator) 
Apparently a great simulator, used to train French Army pilots.

[image]

[This game is available for free in Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/223750/DCS_World_Steam_Edition/), only for Windows OS.
It should be possible to install it on Ubuntu thanks to Steam and Proton (a wine like).
See on [this page](https://www.protondb.com/app/223750#iZKtQScpFL), some have been able to play it, and some don't.

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Graphic Card Nvidia GeForce GT 620
- Nvidia Driver v390.132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought and installed a **new Graphic Card NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660**
and retried to install DCS with **Steam** and **Proton 4.11-13**.
And it works perfectly.
My previous Graphic Card was probably not powerful enough.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Latest DCS version (2.5.6.49798 release on 2020-05-28 as of 2020-06-21) won't start on Lutris 0.5.6. You'll need to revert back to a previous version.

What I did :

- install Lutris
- install DCS (Eagle Dynamics version, not beta nor Steam) from Lutris.
- keep install until begin to download a really big update (~ >70GB)
- cancel the big (~ >70GB) download
- open a console/navigate to DCS/bin directory
- enter that command (from Ubuntu console):

  wine DCS_updater.exe update 2.5.5.41371

or

```
DCS_updater.exe update 2.5.5.41371
```

if you opened a wine console

2.5.5.41371 is the version that presently works with Lutris.

- answer "Yes" when asked to delete already downloaded files (as they are newer and won't work)
- wait for download to complete (big download, but the good one)
- launch DCS from Lutris.
- on first launch, DCS may crash/freeze. Restart it and everything is ok.
- of course, don't update when asked to download latest version.

Enjoy !

TQHien

Comment: Thank you, after the installation, I try to launch the game, I m requested to login, and then I get a black window that quickly disappears and crashes, with this error message in the Lutris console: **wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.Game is considered exited.**

Comment: in the dcs.log I have : _DX11BACKEND: DX11Renderer::init() failed - D3D11CreateDevice() returned E_FAIL_ | _DX11BACKEND: DX11Renderer::shutdown()_ | _GRAPHICSVISTA: DirectX backend initialization error_  | _GRAPHICSVISTA: DirectX backend initialization error_ | _DCS: application shutdown_

Comment: Wine config may need to be adjusted, particularly for Z, which by default points to / (root) And that is not writable for normal use. Change Z to a dir in your user home. I don't have a L drive. Did you change where DCS should be installed ? Lutris FAQ for install scrip says that it should be installed to default dir (C:)

Comment: I finaly installed Ubuntu 20.04 and try again. I solve the `access denied Z:` following your advice to point Z: to a folder in my /home. Thank you. But now the new error is `ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/$LIB/libgamemodeauto.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

Comment: Just to be sure, did you use the Lutris Script to install the game ? It is available from Lutris website : [https://lutris.net/games/dcs-world/](https://lutris.net/games/dcs-world/)

Comment: yes i used the script from Lutris

Answer (score 1):

DCS now runs out of the box with Steam. Proton 7.0 lists DCS explicitly as one of the new supported games.

Nobody knows the future. But i take this as a good sign.